# scripting DAX measures, tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there any way to script dax measures in pbix file? Just in case we would like to populate them in another pbix?

Just like in SQL Server we may right-click on object and have option to script it. Sometimes there are many measure to transfer and endless-ctl-c-v between projects is hopeless. Anyway, still better then writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible yet, but there are some ideas that you can go vote on that are related to this.

[Scripted View of the Data Model](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/8440645-scripted-view-of-the-data-model)

[Duplicate Measure and Format Copy](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13219620-duplicate-measure-and-format-copy)

Add your vote and comment to increase chances that Microsoft will address this.

Comment: Still nothing changed? Maybe there is some app which could do that?

Comment: If you're looking for a separate program, I'd suggest giving [DAX Studio](http://daxstudio.org/) a try. It's free and open source.